# requirejs datatables extra modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, requirejs

I use datatables.net and requirejs -

when i add library -

```
requirejs.config({
    "paths": {
"datatables": "https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.3.0/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min", 
}
```

requirejs stops working: `Mismatched anonymous define()`

if i use

```
"datatables.net": "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
```

everything is working  but 
if i add

```
'datatables.net-fixedColumns' : "https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min",
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: datatables,datatables.net-fixedColumns
```

Comment: This question needs a [mcve] to know what's going on.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid suggestion, but have you tried to use the actual paths, i.e include the `.js` extensions?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?